# Encrypting ASP.NET request and response to avoid "man-in-the-middle" attacks

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl

Is there a technique that uses a good encryption standard to encrypt all requests on an ASP.NET web app over SSL/HTTPS in order to make sure that when the web app is used in a public WiFi connection (cafe, restaurants, hotels, etc) that if there is anything in the network capturing the raw packets that it the data can't be read?

Would the built-in view state encryption be good enough?

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <machineKey validation="3DES" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: See [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178199(v=vs.85).aspx) on _encrypting_ viewstate data (vs. protection from _tampering_ via hash). I think you need to clarify what you need because "all" and "public" may point to solutions like VPN and such...

Comment: Doesn't SSL already do that for you?

Comment: By its nature, SSL already encrypts all data to prevent a MitM attack. Therefore, you don't need to do anything extra to encrypt it, other than ensure your users access your site via HTTPS. What I do is check all incoming requests in my Global.asax file and redirect them to the HTTPS site.

Comment: I'm enforcing SSL on IIS so there is no way around it. As of MitM I thought that I've read it somewhere that over WiFi it is possible to catch the data even on SSL but I could be wrong then.

Comment: Probably you misread it. There is no difference, just ensure that you enforce the use of HTTPS instead HTTP.

Comment: Like I said, I'm enforcing on IIS so there is no way to navigate without HTTPS, and this will prevent any MiTM attacks?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it does, but it is still possible if the hacker becomes the SSL provider

Comment: @WongJiaHau but the fake SSL provider won't be able to fake the server certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the way that you mitigate man-in-the-middle attacks is that you run the site over SSL, which will encrypt the entire channel between the client (web browser) and the server.  This is completely unrelated to the <machineKey> element, which allows the server to round-trip sensitive data via an untrusted client.

However, it is important to identify which particular attacks you're trying to mitigate.  For instance, SSL can help prevent a third party from eavesdropping on or tampering with data in-flight between the client and the server, but it will not mitigate availability attacks against the server.

It's also important to know how to configure this correctly: every page (including the login page) must be served over SSL for the protection to be effective.  You can't have mixed-mode content (an SSL page pointing to an HTTP .js file).  It's best practice to set the HSTS header to offer extra security to clients.

You should know how this integrates into a complete security story for your web site.  Using SSL is not enough. If you have XSS or XSRF (CSRF) holes in your web site, your clients are still vulnerable to malicious third parties.

There's lots of good info here on StackOverflow and in other forums regarding these.  https://owasp.org/ is also a respectable resource.  Finally, if your site is important / sensitive enough that you're concerned about attackers eavesdropping on your traffic, you should consider a professional security auditor.